# How to turning Debug Mode On, Windows server 2012?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, windows-server-2012, workbench

I'm trying to Install YetiShare script, but every time I face this message:

"SQL execution error! Please Turn debug mode On and check carefully a syntax of your SQL dump file."

FYI, my OS: win server 2012 
with IIS manager & php v 5.5 & Workbench 6.0

I don't know how to turn Debug Mode On!

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way is to boot your windows server 2012 using F8 and then choose : debugging mode

hoping this would help :)

Regards,

Comment: That is a different debugging mode.